# Google sheet - A very special kind of dynamic drop down list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could someone please, give me advice about the most effective way to perform this task:

My Spreadsheet contains two sheets (Sheet 1 named "Choice" and Sheet 2 named "Gifts")

Sheet 1 contains three columns:
Rank (from 1 to the total number of owners)
Name (of the owner)
Chosen gift (drop down list)

Sheet 2 contains only one column:
List of gifts

Gifts are unique
There are as many gifts as owners
The owner ranked 1 will choose first.
The owner ranked 2 will be the second to choose his gift, and so on...

What I am trying to do:

When the owner ranked "n" clicks on the drop down list ("Chosen gift"-Sheet 1) related to his name, he can only select gifts that are still available and that have not been chosen by owners ranked from 1 to n-1 yet.

My understanding is that it is necessary to use Google script. Could you please guide me through the main steps ?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8JGtn4ZPb6yOCpTEqLYSJghBbzTb6jNqRGUn-tQ-Ek/copy
You have to filter the list of gifts according to their availability. If you see the red upper-right corner, that means that the gilft is well already distributed. In that case this not an error but a meaningfully indication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mike.

Comment: I will try this out !